# How to filter sub-document in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mlab document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "572b2cdfc80eb653c302f5e9"
},
"year": 2014,
"students": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "know",
        "GPA": 67
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "GPA": 77
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "firstName": "Yossi",
        "lastName": "Haim",
        "GPA": 68
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "firstName": "Chen",
        "lastName": "Si",
        "GPA": 92
    }
]
}
```

Which i get with: (year is also a parameter)

```
gradeM= mongoose.model('Grade',grade);
      gradeM.find({'year':year},'-_id').exec(function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log("err: " + err);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
  });
```

As much as getting data from the collection i'm doing well but i wish to exclude from returned document all students array records in which GPA<90.
Tried some different aggregate ans match functions but i can't seem to get the syntax correct.

End result should look like:

```
 {
   "year": 2014,
   "students": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "firstName": "Chen",
        "lastName": "Si",
        "GPA": 92
    }
]
}
```

I can always loop the document using JS but i'm looking for a way to get the ready result right away.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can $unwind students, filter them, then add to group - please see example below:

```
db.yush.aggregate([
{$match:{"year":2014}},
{
            $unwind : "$students"
        }, {
            $match : {
                "students.GPA" : {
                    $lt : 90
                }                
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$year"
                ,
                students : {
                    $push : "$students"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

and at the end use $project to change _id to year

Have a fun - any comments welcome!

Comment: This looks good , it gives me all GPA>=90 as needed but it returnes it for all years. how can i filter according to the year parameter i'm getting into the function? Thanks a lot

Comment: @YushN added $match phase as a first one to process only selected year

Comment: works great with the explixit year but once i write the parameter year instead (which has the same value) i get [].
Thanks

Comment: @YushN - hmm that's strane - have no idea

Comment: and the winner is: "year":parseInt(year)
@profesor79

next on the list, trying to understand how to use the aggregate callback return as a http response which i can display on the browser

Answer (score 2):

You can try using aggregation

```
gradeM.aggregate( {$match: {year: 2014}},{ $unwind: '$students'},
                   { $match: {'students.GPA': {$lt: 90}}},
                   { $group: {_id: '$_id',
                              year : '$year',
                              students: {$push: {id:'$students.id',
                                                 firstName:'$students.firstName'}}}})
```

Output :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572b2cdfc80eb653c302f5e9"), 
  "year":2014,
   "students" : [ { "id" : 5, "firstName" : "Joe" },
                  { "id" : 3, "firstName" : "Peter" },
                  { "id" : 6, "firstName" : "Yossi" } ] }
```

Also ,You can give try

```
gradeM.aggregate([
    { $match: {year: year}},
    { $project: {
        students: {$filter: {
            input: '$students',
            as: 'students',
            cond: {$lt: ['$$students.GPA', 90]}
        }}
        }}
    ])
```

Comment: first one returnes [] which shouldn't be empty according to the data i have.
second one falls if i'm not mistaken because of mongoDB version that doesn't recognize $filter.
thanks for the help

Comment: Let me try ..just a moment

Comment: nice approach with $filter - like it!

Comment: Thanks alot . Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

Try as following

```
gradeM= mongoose.model('Grade',grade);
  gradeM.find({'year':year, students: { $elemMatch: GPA: { $lt: 90 } }},'-_id').exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log("err: " + err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
  });
```